# Navigate to url by calling function

Tags: javascript, html, function, vbscript

I am working on automating some of the web form filling tasks that we do everyday using VBScript.

I can navigate to the site

```
Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

        oIE.Visible = True
        oIE.navigate ("https://domain.com/")
```

This will take to the home page.

From the Home page, I will have to navigate to another page called "APPLY" before I fill data into it.

If it was a button,

I could use something like this: ->

oIE.Document.All.Item("Button_name").Click

However,  What I have is just a  tag.

```
<a class="out" onmouseout="displayhelp('1');this.className='out'" onmouseover="displayhelp('0');this.className='over'" onclick="RMF00201_setVal('newapp');"> Apply </a>
```

So, it's simply a text that ONCLICK triggers a function.

Looks like it is a Javascript function as I could see the following lines above.

```
<title> … </title>
<script src="../../objserv/RMFGEN01.js" language="JavaScript1.1"></script>
<script src="../../objserv/RMF00201.js" language="JavaScript1.1"></script>
```

When I actually click the "APPLY" text, it executes the function and goes to a URL.

I tried directly going to the url like:

```
oIE.navigate ("https://domain.com/apply")
```

It didn't work.

Any suggestions.
Appreciate all help.

One month into Scripting.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, all you have to do is the following:

```
function RMF00201_setVal(URL){
   window.location.href = URL;
}
```

Where you have this function either directly in the page you're working on, or in one of the included scripts that you showed in your code.

Comment: It didn't work.
I just managed clicking it

 oIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a").item(0).Click

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Dim objIE, objShell, objShellWindows
Dim strURL, strWindow, strURLFound, WShell, i

strURL = "https://domain.com/"
strWindow = "Apply"
Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set oShellWindows = oShell.Windows
Set WShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

strURLFound = False

'To Fix Item Not Found Error
For Each oIE in oShellWindows
next

For i = 0 to oShellWindows.Count - 1
    Set oIE = oShellWindows.Item(i)

On Error Resume Next
  If InStr(Ucase(oShellWindows.Item(i).LocationURL),Ucase(strURL)) Then
     If InStr(UCASE(oShellWindows.Item(i).FullName), "IEXPLORE.EXE") Then
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
           If Instr(oShellWindows.Item(i).document.title,(strWindow)) then

              strURLFound = True

              Exit For
           End If
        End If
     End If
  End If
Next

WShell.AppActivate strWindow
```

This is what I use when trying to access a specific page in Internet Explorer.